# Seeking: Example of how to use jsDoc with the Webstorm IDE (v 4)

Tags: jsdoc, webstorm

I'm still learning js and trying out the Webstorm IDE, which seems sweet (including jumping to var/function declarations).

I can see how to get the template for a jsdoc comment to appear but I'm not experienced with it and looking for an example of how to provide more detail in the comment and how to **view** that detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WebStorm 4.0 supports most of [JSDoc](http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagReference) tags. For example, when you specify @type for variable, completion will work better and assignments of expressions with wrong types will be highlighted as warnings. Element documentation popup appears when Ctrl+Q is pressed on some reference. More specific info about supported tags can be found in JetBrains issue tracker, for example issue [WI-1295](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-1295).

Also, better support for google closure compiler tags is expected in 5th version.

Answer (score 1):

This tutorial might help :

http://blue-walrus.com/2014/04/using-jsdoc/

Its an introduction in how you can enhance your code with jsdoc in webstorm/phpstorm. Goes into @Type, @param, @return plus others.

Answer (score 0):

I feel your pain... I have recently started evaluating WebStorm also, and found the amount of documentation regarding how to integrate JSDoc into your code a bit lacking.

The following page provides a lot of detail about what tags are available, as well as a detailed description of each tag.

http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagReference

Hope that helps!