# All methods on Javascript

Tags: javascript

Where i can find all methods in Javascript.For example all methods on Array,Number and String ?
Im tried this version but doest work for all methods.

```
document.write(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Number));
```

Comment: do you want to know them or do you want your program to know them ? 

By the way you could explain more what you want because (it doesn't work -> yes it's not a factory -> this is a joke) give us the output of what you want and the output you get

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8831130/javascript-documentation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please look at the following reference.

[Reference to Java Script Functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)