# How can I add a description to a function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I would like to add a description to a js function like I do it in C, C++, Python ...

I do this by adding a comment at the top of the definition of the function, in the mentioned languages, but if I use JavaScript (pure, NodeJS, ReactJS) it does not show it.
Ej:

[image: Adding a Description in C++]

Result (When I put the cursor in a call of the function or definition):
[image: Description being shown]

But I this behaviour does not replicate with Js/NodeJs/React.
Just in case I'm using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 10, accepted):

VSCode, like most IDEs, will automatically process [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app) comments. For example:

```
/**
 * Does something nifty.
 *
 * @param   whatsit  The whatsit to use (or whatever).
 * @returns A useful value.
 */
function nifty(whatsit) {
    return /*...*/;
}
```

Here's a screenshot of what using that function is like in VSCode:

[image: VSCode IDE showing the nifty function above being used, and showing a documentation box with the doc comments in it]

You can augment that with types if you want type hints:

```
/**
 * Does something nifty.
 *
 * @param   {number} whatsit  The whatsit to use (or whatever).
 * @returns {string} A useful value.
 */
function nifty(whatsit) {
    return /*...*/;
}
```

---

If you use TypeScript, the types would be part of the code rather than in the JSDoc:

```typescript
// TypeScript example
/**
 * Does something nifty.
 *
 * @param   whatsit  The whatsit to use (or whatever).
 * @returns A useful value.
 */
function nifty(whatsit: number): string {
    return /*...*/;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm not very use to Javascript and I couldn't make it work.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean you can't get the above to work? Or that you couldn't get something *like* this to work, but now you've seen examples, you can?

Comment: Now I do understand it, due to the examples you give to me.